# Migrate from java 8 to java 9

Tags: java, java-9

I want to upgrade my java version from 8 to 9 in my pat project, but I can't find java9 in oracle site, I see the following

> Java SE 9 has reached end of support. Users of Java SE 9 should switch
>   to Java SE 10.
>
> Please visit our Java SE Downloads page to get the current version of
>   Java SE.
>
> You will be redirected to the Java SE Downloads page in 18 seconds.
>   Please update your bookmarks to the Java SE Downloads page.

Can I migrate to java 9?

Comment: Why not migrate to Java 10 as suggested?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html (but note the warnings in red telling you not to use this version)

Comment: You'd need to migrate to Java 10, but this wouldn't be the version you'd take to production because it doesn't offer long-term support (LTS). Version 11 (to be released in September 2018) will be the next version version to offer LTS.

Comment: If you are looking for older versions of Oracle JDK then start at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and click on the "Java Archive" link which brings you to a page for downloading older releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [Java 9 installation](http://jdk.java.net/archive/), but should you? at your own risk
[image]